# Convert EntityModel to DTO Using "Basic" Custom Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

First, I apologise if this is a dupe, finding the right search terms seemed impossible...

We are trying to adopt some best practice and looking at refactoring duplicate code in our projects. On a number of occasions we have something like;

```
public List<EventModel> GetEvents(bool showInactive, bool showPastEvents)
{
    return eventRepository
        .GetEvents(_customerId, showInactive, showPastEvents)
        .Select(e => New EventModel() {  Id = e.EventId, Name = e.EventName, Capacity = e.EventCapacity, Active = e.EventActive })
        .ToList();
}
```

So we tried doing something like this instead;

```
public List<EventModel> GetEvents(bool showInactive, bool showPastEvents)
{
    return eventRepository
        .GetEvents(_customerId, showInactive, showPastEvents)
        .Select(e => ConvertPocoToModel(e))
        .ToList();
}

private EventModel ConvertPocoToModel(TsrEvent tsrEvent)
{
    EventModel eventModel = new EventModel()
    {
        Id = tsrEvent.EventId,
        Name = tsrEvent.EventName,
        Capacity = tsrEvent.EventCapacity,
        Active = tsrEvent.EventActive                
    };
    return eventModel;
}
```

Sometimes this works, but intermittently we get;

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'Bll.Models.EventModel ConvertPocoToModel(Dal.Pocos.TsrEvent)'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

I am aware we could add .ToList() or similar to force the conversion to happen in C# but I believe that means SQL will execute `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT EVentId, EventName, EventCapacity, EventActive`

Can anyone explain;

- Why EF is having issues trying to understand how to handle this simple mapping?
- why it work intermittently?
- How we should be doing it?

Comment: I don't have an answer regarding the first two parts of your question. But for the last past (How should we be doing it): Did you consider the queryable extensions of Automapper for that? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Thanks @AndreKraemer- we aren't using AutoMapper at the moment, but will put it on the table for discussion in the future.

Comment: You get the error because Select function cannot be translated into SQL, because SQL doesn't know what `ConvertPocoToModel(e)` means. I would suggest you to keep original code. In our projects we write in original way and we are ok, we didn't see any problems with that. As I remember you can type `GetEvents(blablabla).ToList().Select(e=>ConvertPocoToModel(e))` to have what you want. You have to use ToList() right after GetEvents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework doesnt know how to translate your method. You have to use method which returns `Expression<Func<TsrEvent,EventModel>>` or an property which stores it.

```
public List<EventModel> GetEvents(bool showInactive, bool showPastEvents)
{
    return eventRepository
        .GetEvents(_customerId, showInactive, showPastEvents)
        .Select(ConvertPocoToModelExpr)
        .ToList();
}

private static Expression<Func<TsrEvent,EventModel>> ConvertPocoToModelExpr =>  (x)=>new EventModel()
    {
        Id = x.EventId,
        Name = x.EventName,
        Capacity = x.EventCapacity,
        Active = x.EventActive                
    };
```

Comment: Perfect- thanks, I will give this a try and read up/learn about Expressions/Functions.
Any ideas why our approach has intermittently worked in the past?

Comment: Only idea i have is that, GetEvents() returned something other than IQueryable of sql query. For example IEnumerable of collection which already existed. It's hard to tell without EventRepository implementation

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware about the differences between an `IEnumerable` and an `IQueryable`.

An `IEnumerable` object holds everything to enumerate over the sequence. You can ask for the first element, and once you've got an element you can ask for the next one, as long as there is a next one. The `IEnumerable` is meant to be processes locally by your process.

Enumeration at its lowest level is done by asking for the Enumerator and repeatedly calling MoveNext, until you don't need anymore elements. Like this:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = ...
IEnumerator<Student> studentEnumerator = students.GetEnumerator();
while (studentEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // there is still a Student to process:
    Student student = studentEnumerator.Current;
    ProcessStudent(student);
}
```

You can do this explicitly, or call it implicitly using `foreach` or one of the LINQ functions.

On the other hand, an `IQueryable` is meant to be processed by a different process, usually a database management system. The `IQueryable` holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` expresses the query that must be performed in some generic format. The `Provider` knows who must execute the query (usually a database management system), and the language that this process uses (usually something SQL like).

As soon as you start enumerating by calling GetEnumerator, the `Expression` is sent to the `Provider`, who tries to translate the `Expression` into SQL  and executes the query. The fetched data is put into an enumerable sequence, and the enumerator is returned.

**Back to your question**

The problem is, that SQL does not know `ConvertPocoToModel`. Hence your provider can't convert the `Expression`. The compiler can't detect this, because it does not know how smart your `Provider` is. That is why you don't get this error until you call `GetEnumerator`, in your case by calling `ToList`.

**Solution**

The solution is to make a function that changes the expression. The easiest method would be an extension function. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx). This way you can use it like any other LINQ method:

```
public static IQueryable<EventModel> ToEventModels(this IQueryable<TsrEvent> tsrEvents)
{
    return tsrEvent.Select(tsrEvent =>  new EventModel
    {
        Id = tsrEvent.EventId,
        Name = tsrEvent.EventName,
        Capacity = tsrEvent.EventCapacity,
        Active = tsrEvent.EventActive                
    };
}
```

Note that I omit the `()` in the constructor: SQL can't call constructors!

Usage:

```
var result = dbContext.TsrEvents
     .Where(tsrEvent => tsrEvent.Active && tsrEvent.Date == Today)
     .ToEventModels()
     .GroupBy(...)
     ... etc
```

Or, if your `GetEvents` returns an `IQueryable<TsrEvents>`

```
return eventRepository.GetEvents(_customerId, showInactive, showPastEvents)
      .ToEventModels();
```

**Final Remark**

It is better to let your data-fetch-functions return `IQueryable<...>` and `IEnumerable<...>` as long as possible. Let only the end-user materialize the query. It would be a waste of processing power if you do the `ToList()` and your caller only wants to do `FirstOrDefault()`